# Remove a list of strings in a specific position only?

Tags: vba, full-text-search, ms-word

I need to delete every found (from a list) word that is in the first position of any paragraph.

My closest-to-working effort fails to consistently erase those words found in the first position of a paragraph, and occasionally deletes words that are elsewhere in the paragraph. However, it makes the same errors, in the same places, on each run-through. It looks like this:

```
For Each para In docCurrent.Paragraphs
    firstword = para.Range.Words(1)
    Set firstwd = para.Range.Words(1)
    firstchar = para.Range.Characters(1)

    Set searchrange = para.Range.Words(1)
    searchrange.SetRange Start:=firstwd.Start, End:=firstwd.End
    For Each wrdRef In docRef.Words
        If Asc(Left(wrdRef, 1)) > 32 Then
            match = wrdRef
            i = Len(match)

            If Left(firstword, i) = match Then
                With searchrange.Find
                  .Wrap = wdFindStop
                  .Text = wrdRef
                  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next wrdRef
Next para
```

If anyone can spot a glaring error or recommend a better (or more efficient) method, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I think your question needs to be a lot more specific. Focus on a single problem you're facing and post just the relevant portions of code that pertain to it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think the problem is with the searchrange portion, because I don't seem to be setting it in a manner that confines the search effectively. If I could fix the searchrange (I mean both correct it and make it stay where I put it), then even this clumsy code would get the job done.

Comment: so:  How do I confine my search area?

setting a limited searchrange didn't work for me in either program...

Comment: Edit your question to focus on just that and I'll bet you get a lot more responses.

Comment: Sorry, is it best to just overwrite my original question, edit, or ask anew?

Comment: how do you define a list of word which you compare with first word in paragraph? and how you define to what you want replace the words found.

Comment: I am reading the (long) list of words-to-replace from another document, and defined .Replacement.Text (under With Selection.Find) as empty ("") for this program. Those steps worked, I just wasn't setting my search region effectively enough - luckily, your answer to avoid using Search altogether worked perfectly despite my inadequately-defined question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right you don't need to have such a complicated solution with `Find >> Replace` model in it. You could use simple Word objects and Word hierarchy. Check the following solution.

```
For Each para In docCurrent.Paragraphs
    Set firstWd = para.Range.Words(1)
        For Each wrdRef In docRef.Words
            If Asc(Left(wrdRef, 1)) > 32 Then   '??!!

                'remove spaces and be careful about text vs. binary compare
                If UCase(Replace(firstWd, " ", "")) = UCase(wrdRef) Then

                    firstWd.Text = "YourNewWordHere"

                End If
            End If
        Next wrdRef
Next para
```

Comment: That's perfect! It works, it's simpler/efficient, and I think I was embarrassingly overcomplicating this step because of how many others there were. But with this simpler approach, I should be able to get those working, too. Thanks so much.